# Set text color in a single row listview android

Tags: android, listview

`final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                        false);
                String[] values = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

my question is how to change a single row item text color. I've seen that making a new ArrayAdapter may get that, but not uunderstanding how.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a **CustomAdapter** to handle this instead of using the `ArrayAdapter`. Extend the `ArrayAdapter`/`BaseAdapter` and override the `getView()` method and inside the `getView()` method according to your condition you can change the color of the text on your `textView.setTextColor` of your required `TextView`.

You can see how to implement this in this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)